# Strange recursive definition in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, infinite-loop

Consider the following Scheme definition:

```
(define f (lambda () (procedure? f)))
```

Strangely, when I evaluate `(f)` I get `#t`. The question is: why does this evaluation terminate? I was expecting it to loop indefinitely. What does the inner `lambda` evaluate to, given that `f` hasn't yet been defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no recursion involved here.

When you execute this code, a procedure `f` is defined (not executed):

```
> (define f (lambda () (procedure? f)))
> f
#<procedure:f>
```

When you then execute it, it checks if there is a procedure associated with the symbol f, which is true at that point in time, so it returns `#t`:

```
> (f)
#t
```

To be recursive, the procedure would have to call itself using `(f)`.

Comment: I see. To me a recursive definition of a function meant **any reference** to it in its definition, not just calls to it. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Now I think I understand it better. Consider the following lambda expression: (lambda () (/ 1 0)); remarkably, the interpreter accepts it. Should I understand that a lambda expression never evaluates its body (this being evaluated only in function applications)?

Comment: @AlexM. Yes. It's evaluated when called, not when defined.

Comment: @AlexM. Just put an extra pair of parentheses around your expression and you'll get a division by 0 error.